# how to get average ratio

Tags: bash, average, bc

I am creating a bash script to get the total number of transactions in a day, It'll include total, success and failed.

So far I could get those numbers, but I also need to create a successful average and failed average.

Now, let say that I got 1000 transactions which 900 were successful and 100 failed. For instance we can say that we have a success ratio of 90 % and a 10 % failure

When I try to do the maths I cannot get those percentages. I am saving the transactions number into variables so I have

```
"$TOTAL"=1000
"$SUCCESS"=900
"$FAILED"=100
```

I have tried the next codes failing in every attempt

```
AVERAGE=("$FAILED"*100)/"$TOTAL" | bc
AVERAGE=(\("$FAILED"*100)/"$TOTAL" | bc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$ TOTAL=1000
$ SUCCESS=900
$ FAILED=100
$ AVERAGE=$((FAILED*100/TOTAL))
$ echo $AVERAGE
10
```

Comment: Damn, it was so easy now that you put it like that... Thanks though it worked excellent!!!

Comment: Hello JS웃 I have another issue related to the same situation, how can I make it floating?! I have tried `AVES="$((SUCCESS*100/TOTAL))" | bc -l` but it didn't work, could you help me out with it?!

Comment: @AntonioPerezOseguera `bash` won't do floating. In that case you will have to use `awk`.